# Why is the simple string "Guido" a valid statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this a valid statement in Python?

```
"Guido"
```

This tripped me up with a multi-line string where I did *not* properly use parens:

```
# BAD
message = "Guido"
" van Rossum"

# GOOD
message = ("Guido"
" van Rossum")
```

Is it purely for the repl or is there some other reasoning for it?

Comment: Any expression is a valid statement. Also, docstrings.

Comment: Why would it *not* be a valid statement?

Comment: This is also how docstrings work. No special syntax required.

Comment: Catching statements that are technically valid but that suggest that you might have missed something is a large part of why pylint exists!  http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0105

Comment: This shouldn't be surprising. Almost any language I know of lets you have a string expression without assignment. It's not _entirely_ a legitimate question because it's psychological. "Why does Python allow `'` to quote strings in addition to `"`?" seems about equally pointless to speculate about. That's just how the language was designed.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions are statements in Python (and most other imperative languages) for several good reasons:

1. What if a function, like `foo()` does something useful but *also* returns a value? `foo()` would be an invalid statement if the language didn't allow us to implicitly discard the return value.
2. Docstrings! They are just strings that happen to be the first statement of a module/class/function, so no special syntax was needed to support them.

In general, it's hard for the interpreter to determine whether an expression might have side effects. So it's been designed to not even try; it simply evaluates the expression, even if it's a simple constant, and discards the result.

To check for such mistakes as you mentioned, and many others, `pylint` can be helpful. It has a [specific warning](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0105) for this very case. However, it seems to not catch the mistake in your exact example code (using PyLint version 2.4.4); might be a bug.